# Thermomechanical problems

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

I would like to know where I can find the coupled field examples / nb files using Mathematica/`NDsolve` (e.g. Thermomechanical Problems)?

Comment: What leads you to the assumption that there were such examples?

Comment: As I can only find the thermal example nb file...

Comment: @FEAPMAN To which files do you refer? Could you be more specific?

Comment: @MarcoB, https://www.wolfram.com/language/11/partial-differential-equations/solve-an-initial-value-problem-for-the-heat-equati.html?product=mathematica

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This [talk](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/8971/) at Wolfram Technology Conference 2014 contains one example of themomechanical problem.

If you need more advanced field coupling functionality then I suggest you take a look at [AceFEM](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tags/acegen/info) package. Although I admit that the learning curve might be steep at the beginning.

Comment: Thanks for posting the link. I wanted to do that, but just did not get to it.